# Como depurar um código no JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsfiddle

Existe alguma forma de depurar/debugar um código no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? Geralmente nas ferramentas de desenvolvimento do chrome aparecem vários script's, qual o caminho correto para colocar os breakpoint's para debugar o código? Existe alguma maneira de debugar via código?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando `debugger;` em alguma linha do seu código, assim o depurador vai parar ali e você pode debuggar.

```js
document.getElementById('teste').onclick = function (){
  debugger;
  alert('teste');
}
```

```html
<button id='teste'>Teste</button>
```

Ele funciona até mesmo aqui no StackSnippet. 
Vale lembrar que é necessário estar com o Developer Tools aberto